# Get Permission to Scan Barcodes on iOS with Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, qr-code

I'm using [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) to scan barcodes in my Flutter app and it works fine for Android, but when I try to scan for iOS a pop-up appears and looks like:

[image]

I'm using the descriptions Flutter code that looks like the following:

```
QRView(
                        key: qrKey,
                        onQRViewCreated: (controller) => {
                              controller.scannedDataStream.listen((code) async {
                               ...
                              })
                            })
```

And in my Info.plist file I have the following fields:

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Camera permission is required to scan QR codes.</string>
```

However even with these settings set, I can't seem to figure out how to have access to the camera. Thanks for any help.

---

**Update**
I followed @EvgeniyTrubilo suggestion and used [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) to request permission using the following code:

```
void getCameraPermission() async {
    print(await Permission.camera.status); // prints PermissionStatus.granted
    var status = await Permission.camera.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      final result = await Permission.camera.request();
      if (result.isGranted) {
        setState(() {
          canShowQRScanner = true;
        });
      } else {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('Please enable camera to scan barcodes')));
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        canShowQRScanner = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

The first time this code was executed it successfully requested permission to access camera, and once permission was granted, the same error showed up. Sequential tries the print statement at the top of the above function said the Permission was granted??

---

**Update 2x**
Just realized you can mock the camera in an iOS simulator like you can on Android. I will try this on an actual device and update.

Comment: check out below answer, you are just one line of code away from asking permissions on flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler). With this, you could ask for camera permission before build QRView. Of course, you should build QRView after camera permission is enabled.
I'm not sure it would be right solution for your issue, but I think that would be an awesome improvement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I think it is pointing me closer to the issue, but I'm still experiencing problems, look at my updated question.

Comment: If you are trying this on IOS simulator, you are wrong. Because ios simulator doesn't support camera features. Please try on actual device.

Comment: In my case I have given camera access from settings, but after that when opening QR in Ios device, It opens and just closing.